# Why is ~1 suggested edit waiting for review?

Tags: support

Today I noticed this:

[image]

Why does it say `~1` and not `1` suggested edit pending approval?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely, due to the #s being cached, so they didn't want to pretend to be exact ("~" means "[approximately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Common_use)").

As a matter of fact, half the time the # I see is actually wrong compared to review counts I see in the actual queues.